# Poor icon graphics on windows excecutable app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Why my electron app has poor icon graphics

I recently create and electron app however when i package it with electron rebuild the icon graphics of the installer and installed app are really poor on windows.

The icon am using is **512x512** and i don't have the same problem when i package it to Linux executable ***.deb*** file.

[image]

As you can see the icon is not perfect.

Is there a way to improve the icon quality?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? The accepted answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `512x512` icon was scaled down to fit with windows desktop's icons's size.

I would suggest you to create an ico file from your icon, this file contains following multiple sizes: `16, 24, 32, 48, 64, 128, 256`.

After that, put your icon under `build` directory with name as `icon.ico`

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by converting png to .ico here:

https://convertio.co/png-ico/

now download and rename the file to icon.ico and drag it into your project

idk how unoptimized this solution is, but at least fixes the problem

btw sometimes icon is kinda cached but when you install the app it gets updated.